# Building a multipage shiny application - Pros and Cons of renderUI() vs extending ui.R

Tags: r, shiny

I am building a multipage shiny application - that is, the application consists of several (independent) main pages with buttons to go forward and (sometimes) backwards.
As far as I can see - and in line with [the general two possibilities to build a shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47637753/r-shiny-creating-widgets-in-ui-r-vs-renderui-uioutput) -, there are two main approaches

1. Build the pages in the userinterface (`ui.R`), then hide and show each pages accordingly. This is the approach followed by @daattali [in this demonstration app](https://github.com/daattali/advanced-shiny/tree/master/multiple-pages), using `shinyjs` to hide and show each page. I suppose there could also be ways to [do this by using `navbar()`, `navlist()` or `tabsetPanel()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53501064/building-multipage-shiny-application-userside-in-ui-r-by-using-navbarpanel-a), if one can hide the navigation bar oder navigation list. This has the advantage of [updating pages simply via `updateTabsetPanel()`, `updateNavbarPage()` or `updateNavlistPabel()`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/0.14/updateTabsetPanel.html), rendering `shinyjs` unneccesary.
2. Second approach is to build the pages on the serverside with `renderUI()` and limiting `ui.R` to a stub. This is the approach followed [for example by TomW](http://www.open-meta.org/technology/demo-app-r-for-multi-page-url-based-shiny-web-sites/), limiting ui to `renderUI()` and [doing everything else server side](https://github.com/open-meta/uiStub/blob/master/app/app.R); and the approach treated in [this discussion](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-app-composed-of-many-many-pages/7698/3)

So my question is:

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each approach respectively what are situations where you should or should not use each approach?

I will provide an answer as to what I know at the moment, but would be glad of corrections and additions.

Answer (score 0):

### Building Pages User-Side

**Advantages**

- Ui only needs to be built once, saving network traffic and server load.
- Better control of availability: UI is always built before the server, so [all pages are availabe at initialisation time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53448767/shiny-modules-store-parameters-additional-argument-already-when-creating-modu#comment93795310_53453033).
- Inputs do not need to be reinitialised when page is displayed again.
- Order (and thus eventually numbering, for example of CSS-classes) is obvious.

**Disadvantages**

- If "same" inputs are to be displayed on several pages, two inputs have to be [synchronised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21888816/4177265), instead of [simply rebuilding the input using the old value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33143034/4177265).
- Bloated ui.R, possibly separating ui and server logics;
- Big Page user side, since all pages are built at once and only hidden from user`s view

### Building Pages Server-Side

**Advantages**

- Better control and possibility to render pages dynamically.
- Possibility to use [modules for each page](https://community.rstudio.com/t/shiny-app-composed-of-many-many-pages/7698/3).

**Disadvantages**

- network traffic and server load; less control of availabily
- Possibilites of styling elements per CSS which rely on internal counting of CSS classes are harder to achieve. One example is to [color sliderInputs in different colors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36906265/how-to-color-sliderbar-sliderinput).

So I would say: 
If you have only few pages, you know the sequence beforehand or you want users to switch back and forth between the pages, build it user-side. If you have a huge number of pages, call pages only once or need to include dynamic input, build it server-side.