# R Shiny: create dynamic UI from selected input

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity, shinyjs

I'm trying to create a dynamic UI that produces N amount of sections based on the number of selected variables from a `selectInput()` command. For each variable selected, I want to have its own section that lets you further specify other attributes for that variable (e.g. if it's numeric or character, how to impute missing values, etc.)

I have experience with `insertUI()` and `removeUI()` and was able to produce a small example of what I want it to look like. The section of my code that does this looks like this:

```r
    insertUI(
      selector = '#ui_test',
      ui = tags$div(id = "extra_criteria",
                    h4("Covariate 1 (example)"),
                    selectInput("cov_1_class", "Covariate class",
                                choices = c("numeric","character")),
                    selectInput("cov_1_impute", "Impute",
                                choices = c("default","mean","mode","median")),
                    textInput("cov_1_impute_default_level", "Impute default level","0"),
                    tags$hr(),
                    h4("Covariate 2 (example)"),
                    selectInput("cov_2_class", "Covariate class",
                                choices = c("numeric","character")),
                    selectInput("cov_2_impute", "Impute",
                                choices = c("default","mean","mode","median")),
                    textInput("cov_2_impute_default_level", "Impute default level","0"),
                    tags$hr(),
                    h4("Covariate 3 (example)"),
                    selectInput("cov_3_class", "Covariate class",
                                choices = c("numeric","character")),
                    selectInput("cov_3_impute", "Impute",
                                choices = c("default","mean","mode","median")),
                    textInput("cov_3_impute_default_level", "Impute default level","0"),
                    tags$hr(),
                    h4("Covariate 4 (example)"),
                    selectInput("cov_4_class", "Covariate class",
                                choices = c("numeric","character")),
                    selectInput("cov_4_impute", "Impute",
                                choices = c("default","mean","mode","median")),
                    textInput("cov_4_impute_default_level", "Impute default level","0")
      )
    )
```

What I want to accomplish is to make the section above robust and dynamic in the sense that if the user only selects 2 variables, then I'd only want to create sections `h4("Covariate 1 (example)")` and `h4("Covariate 2 (example)")`. For example, if `age` and `sex` were selected then I'd want my section to look like:

```r
    insertUI(
      selector = '#ui_test',
      ui = tags$div(id = "extra_criteria",
                    h4("Age"),
                    selectInput("age_class", "Covariate class",
                                choices = c("numeric","character")),
                    selectInput("age_impute", "Impute",
                                choices = c("default","mean","mode","median")),
                    textInput("age_impute_default_level", "Impute default level","0"),
                    tags$hr(),
                    h4("Sex"),
                    selectInput("sex_class", "Covariate class",
                                choices = c("numeric","character")),
                    selectInput("sex_impute", "Impute",
                                choices = c("default","mean","mode","median")),
                    textInput("sex_impute_default_level", "Impute default level","0")
                    
      )
    )
```

I was initially going to approach this by looping over the variables in the selected input and creating a long character string of the desired output (i.e. the chunks of `h4(Covariate N)`), and then passing that through `eval(parse(text="..."))`. Something that in the end will look like this:

```r
    insertUI(
      selector = '#ui_test',
      ui = tags$div(id = "extra_criteria",
                    eval(parse(text="..."))
      )
    )
```

where the `"..."` section are the chunks of `h4("Covariate N)` treated as a character string. Now, I don't know if this will work but it's the only approach I have at the moment. Is there a better way of approaching this problem, perhaps with some of the functions within `shiny`? Any help or advice will be greatly appreciated. My mock example can be found below:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage("Test",id="navbarPage",
             tabPanel("First tab", id = "first_tab",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          selectInput('covariates', 'Select covariates', choices = c("age","sex","race","bmi"), multiple=TRUE, selectize=TRUE), 
                          actionButton("set.covariates","Set"),
                          tags$hr(),
                          tags$div(id = 'ui_test')
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          verbatimTextOutput("list")
                        )
                      )
             ))
))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    if (is.null(input$covariates) || input$covariates == "") {
      shinyjs::disable("set.covariates")
      
    } else {
      shinyjs::enable("set.covariates")
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$set.covariates, {
    shinyjs::disable("set.covariates")
  })
  
  prep.list <- eventReactive(input$set.covariates,{
    cov <- input$covariates
    timeIndep.list <- NULL
    for(L0.i in seq_along(cov)){
      timeIndep.list[[L0.i]] <- list("categorical"=FALSE,
                                     "impute"=NA,
                                     "impute_default_level"=NA)
    }
    names(timeIndep.list) <- cov
    return(timeIndep.list)
  })
  
  output$list <- renderPrint({
    prep.list()
  })
  
  observeEvent(req(input$set.covariates), {
    insertUI(
      selector = '#ui_test',
      ui = tags$div(id = "extra_criteria",
                    h4("Covariate 1 (example)"),
                    selectInput("cov_1_class", "Covariate class",
                                choices = c("numeric","character")),
                    selectInput("cov_1_impute", "Impute",
                                choices = c("default","mean","mode","median")),
                    textInput("cov_1_impute_default_level", "Impute default level","0"),
                    tags$hr(),
                    h4("Covariate 2 (example)"),
                    selectInput("cov_2_class", "Covariate class",
                                choices = c("numeric","character")),
                    selectInput("cov_2_impute", "Impute",
                                choices = c("default","mean","mode","median")),
                    textInput("cov_2_impute_default_level", "Impute default level","0"),
                    tags$hr(),
                    h4("Covariate 3 (example)"),
                    selectInput("cov_3_class", "Covariate class",
                                choices = c("numeric","character")),
                    selectInput("cov_3_impute", "Impute",
                                choices = c("default","mean","mode","median")),
                    textInput("cov_3_impute_default_level", "Impute default level","0"),
                    tags$hr(),
                    h4("Covariate 4 (example)"),
                    selectInput("cov_4_class", "Covariate class",
                                choices = c("numeric","character")),
                    selectInput("cov_4_impute", "Impute",
                                choices = c("default","mean","mode","median")),
                    textInput("cov_4_impute_default_level", "Impute default level","0")
      )
    )})
  
  observeEvent({input$covariates}, {
    removeUI(selector = '#extra_criteria')
  })
  
  
})

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Maybe something from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62526706/how-to-extract-element-name-not-value-from-a-list-in-r-shiny-selectinput) can help (especially the comments from Paul)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the description page of `insertUI` function, it says:

> Unlike renderUI(), the UI generated with insertUI() is persistent:
> once it's created, it stays there until removed by removeUI(). Each
> new call to insertUI() creates more UI objects, in addition to the
> ones already there (all independent from one another). To update a
> part of the UI (ex: an input object), you must use the appropriate
> render function or a customized reactive function.

So you cannot use `insertUI` here. Instead, use `renderUI` function with `uiOutput` to dynamically generate ui element.

Next, to generate a ui multiple times based on selection, you can use `lapply`. Since the number of iteration will be dependent on the number of items in the vector, which is the `input$` object; the number of generated ui will be based on number of selection.

I think the code below solves your problem:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
  navbarPage("Test",id="navbarPage",
             tabPanel("First tab", id = "first_tab",
                      sidebarLayout(
                        sidebarPanel(
                          selectInput('covariates', 'Select covariates', choices = c("age","sex","race","bmi"), multiple=TRUE, selectize=TRUE), 
                          actionButton("set.covariates","Set"),
                          tags$hr(),
                          uiOutput("covariateop")
                        ),
                        mainPanel(
                          verbatimTextOutput("list")
                        )
                      )
             ))
))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  observe({
    if (is.null(input$covariates) || input$covariates == "") {
      shinyjs::disable("set.covariates")
      
    } else {
      shinyjs::enable("set.covariates")
    }
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$set.covariates, {
    shinyjs::disable("set.covariates")
  })
  
  prep.list <- eventReactive(input$set.covariates,{
    cov <- input$covariates
    timeIndep.list <- NULL
    for(L0.i in seq_along(cov)){
      timeIndep.list[[L0.i]] <- list("categorical"=FALSE,
                                     "impute"=NA,
                                     "impute_default_level"=NA)
    }
    names(timeIndep.list) <- cov
    return(timeIndep.list)
  })
  
  output$list <- renderPrint({
    prep.list()
  })
  
  observeEvent(req(input$set.covariates), {
    insertUI(
      selector = '#ui_test',
      ui = tags$div(id = "extra_criteria",
                    h4("Covariate 1 (example)"),
                    selectInput("cov_1_class", "Covariate class",
                                choices = c("numeric","character")),
                    selectInput("cov_1_impute", "Impute",
                                choices = c("default","mean","mode","median")),
                    textInput("cov_1_impute_default_level", "Impute default level","0"),
                    tags$hr(),
                    h4("Covariate 2 (example)"),
                    selectInput("cov_2_class", "Covariate class",
                                choices = c("numeric","character")),
                    selectInput("cov_2_impute", "Impute",
                                choices = c("default","mean","mode","median")),
                    textInput("cov_2_impute_default_level", "Impute default level","0"),
                    tags$hr(),
                    h4("Covariate 3 (example)"),
                    selectInput("cov_3_class", "Covariate class",
                                choices = c("numeric","character")),
                    selectInput("cov_3_impute", "Impute",
                                choices = c("default","mean","mode","median")),
                    textInput("cov_3_impute_default_level", "Impute default level","0"),
                    tags$hr(),
                    h4("Covariate 4 (example)"),
                    selectInput("cov_4_class", "Covariate class",
                                choices = c("numeric","character")),
                    selectInput("cov_4_impute", "Impute",
                                choices = c("default","mean","mode","median")),
                    textInput("cov_4_impute_default_level", "Impute default level","0")
      )
    )})
  
  observeEvent(req(input$set.covariates), {
    output$covariateop <- renderUI({  
      lapply(input$covariates, function(x){
      
        tags$div(id = paste0("extra_criteria_for_", x),
                 h4(x),
                 selectInput("cov_1_class", "Covariate class",
                             choices = c("numeric","character")),
                 selectInput("cov_1_impute", "Impute",
                             choices = c("default","mean","mode","median")),
                 textInput("cov_1_impute_default_level", "Impute default level","0"),
                 tags$hr()
        )
      })
    })
    
  })
  
  observeEvent({input$covariates}, {
    removeUI(selector = '#extra_criteria')
  })
  
  
})

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```